# Gapping out edge modes by backscattering

Tags: quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory, tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

I was reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7355) paper by Michael Levin about protected edge states without symmetry. In the introduction, he makes the argument that backscattering terms or other perturbations gap out left and right moving modes in equal numbers. How can we understand in general without making the thermal/hall conductance argument?